# form POST erases the view

Tags: php, html, forms, post

How do I get my very simple view's html items to re-appear after a form's POST?

I lay out the html controls below, then when the user selects the
'Upload' submit button, a file is uploaded (successfully) but all
the previously-laid-out view elements disappear.  Again, the upload
of the file works fine.  It's just that the html controls I displayed
on index.php vanish when the form gets uploaded and the browser window
is blank.

How do I get my very simple view back after a form's POST?

**THIS IS index.php:**

```
<body>
<img src="/theWebsite/images/banner2.jpg" /img>
<br />

<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="showAnAlert(){}" />
     // other buttons and text field html elements not shown

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file-upload.php" method="POST">
      Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>

 </body>
```

**Here is file-upload.php**:

```
<?php
    $target = "upload/";
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;

    $uploadingFile = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'] ;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))
    {
        // I thought the problem was this 'echo' but the main view still goes blank after
         // I commented this out here....
        //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has been uploaded";
     }
     else {
            // echo "errmsg"
           }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting your form to `file-upload.php`, you do not redirect it back to `index.php` where the HTML resides.  You need to call a redirect after doing your form processing:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))
{
    // I thought the problem was this 'echo' but the main view still goes blank after
     // I commented this out here....
    //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has been uploaded";

    // Redirect back....
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/index.php");
    // Always call exit() right after a redirection header to prevent further script execution.
    exit();
 }
 else {
        // echo "errmsg"
 }
```

You may also need to redirect in your error condition.  In that case, put the `header()` call at the very end.

Comment: Shaka dudes!  That did me!  Only thing that bugs me about StackOverflow is you can only 'accept' one answer -- in my experience I find myself learning from everyone who helps out -- thanks guys I'm good to go on this one.

Comment: @wantTheBest: Michael had the most complete answer (I upvoted him too ).

Answer (score 2):

The file-upload.php file needs to either redirect the user back to your index.php once the upload is complete OR needs to include the original index.php file at the bottom.

I vote that you either do a redirect back OR simply remove the file-upload.php file altogether and handle it in your index.php file.

Comment: Thanks, and this will sound naive, but how do I 'redirect the user back to index.php' ?

Comment: @wantTheBest see the `header()` call in my answer below for how to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

For your form's action, specify the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] variable:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
```

Then be sure to add the logic to handle processing the form in the same .php file that outputs the html for your form.  Another method is to have a header() call that redirects to your form again:

```
<form action="process_form.php" method="POST">
```

then, in process_form.php:

```
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/form_page.html");
```